# Remember variable troughout composers and getting records from that

Tags: php, session, laravel-4, composer-php

Basically, what i have is this:

In the HomeComposer i retreive a set of records

```
$posts = Post::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get()->take(3);
```

at the first time the homecomposer is called, i want the first 3 records,

the second time, the 4th, 5th, 6th,

the third time the 7th, 8th, 9th

How do I do this? Keep in mind, when I use a session, the next time the web page is loaded, **the number has to start at 3 again.**

Comment: Look at the pagination docs: http://laravel.com/docs/pagination

Answer (score 1):

Unless i mis-understand what you're trying to do, it sounds like Eloquent's `paginate()` should do the job.

**Controller:**

```
$posts = Post::orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(3);

return View::make('posts.index', ['posts' => $posts]);
```

**View:** ( assuming `/app/views/posts/index.blade.php`)

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
    {{ $post->id }}
@endofreach

{{ $posts->links() }}
```

[Source](http://laravel.com/docs/pagination#usage)